# Cascading WMS/WFS in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, wms

I am planning to use the WMS and WFS Cascading functionalities of Geoserver in order to get some layers from other Geoserver instance. I understand, that using the Cascading requires of creating store/workspace in my Geoserver.

And I can see these (workspace/store/layer) created also in the geoserver/data directory.

I have a basic architecture question: Are these layers copied from the remote Geoserver to my data directory of my local geoserver? Or what I see is just a shortcut to the remote geoserver?

[image]

Comment: The workspace is just a name(space). The store is the "data", and the layer is a view of that data. Remoting is a proxy of the layer (not a full copy of the store, which isn't available in any case). You might get some temporary storage on your geoserver (e.g. in the case of reprojection), but not a full copy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No copies, GeoServer will act as a client to the other server on a as needed basis, doing GetMap and GetFeature to the remote server every time it needs to respond to a local request.

Comment: I see. Thank you. This clarifies things. So the whole structure adds one more "layer" of interaction, which potentially can slow things up a bit; meaning the communication between the client Geoserver and the other Geoserver. So perhaps an alternative in getting data from a remote geoserver, would be to build a remote service which bypass my client geoserver and interacts directly with the other geoserver.

Comment: Yes well, cascading is normally used only if the client cannot talk directly to the remote server, or if the remote server is not giving you an essential feature (e.g., reprojection to a certain CRS, or a specific output format) and the cascading server can add it on the fly.